# Error: Transaction reverted: function returned an unexpected amount of data

Tags: solidity, transactions, nft

I am making an auction house that auction NFTs and burn the current auctionned NFT if there are no bidders at the end of the auction. Everything works except that if there are no bidders at the end of the auction, the burning doesn't go through because of this error : `Error: Transaction reverted: function returned an unexpected amount of data`.

The thing is that I am using the Openzeppelin burn() function which doesn't return anything and I don't understand how this error occur.

The architecture is made of 2 contracts.

1. The NFT itself with this burn function :
       `` /// @notice Call the ERC721 `_burn()` function which burn an NFT and sends it to the address(0). /// @param econNFTId the id of the NFT you want to burn. function burn(uint256 econNFTId) public onlyMinter { console.log("Calling the burn function"); _burn(econNFTId); } `` with the _burn() function being : ```    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal virtual {

   ```
    console.log("Inside the _burn function");
    address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);

    console.log("owner is ", owner);

    _beforeTokenTransfer(owner, address(0), tokenId);

    // Clear approvals
    _approve(address(0), tokenId);

    _balances[owner] -= 1;
    delete _owners[tokenId];

    emit Transfer(owner, address(0), tokenId);
    console.log("Finished running the _burn() function");
   ```

   }```

And the auction house with the settling function being : ```    function _settleAuction() internal {
IEconAuctionHouse.Auction memory _auction = auction;

````
    require(_auction.startTime != 0, "Auction hasn't begun");
    require(!_auction.settled, 'Auction has already been settled');
    require(block.timestamp >= _auction.endTime, "Auction hasn't completed");

    auction.settled = true;

    if (_auction.bidder == address(0)) {
        console.log("first if `_auction.bidder == address(0)` is true");
        econNFT.burn(_auction.econNFTId);
        console.log("BURNING ENDED");
    } else {
        console.log("first else is true");
        econNFT.transferFrom(address(this), _auction.bidder, _auction.econNFTId);
    }

    if (_auction.amount > 0) {
        console.log("Second if `_auction.amount > 0` is true");
        _safeTransferETHWithFallback(owner(), _auction.amount);
    }

    console.log("Just before the event AuctionSettled");

    emit AuctionSettled(_auction.econNFTId, _auction.bidder, _auction.amount);
    console.log("Auction finished running");
}```
````

And the line `console.log("BURNING ENDED");` doesn't go through on the auction house, which mean that the burn doesn't end and revert.
Do you have any idea why that could occur ?

Thank you very much